# Combining two ratios of the same mass to create a new ratio

Tags: solution-verification, ratio

This was stuck on this question wondering if you could help?

> Two solutions, each of mass 1L, has a ratio of liquid A to liquid B as
> 1:6 and 1:8 respectively.  Both solutions are mixed together to create
> one
>
> Find the new ratio of liquid A to liquid B in the new solution

I would also like to know how this could be done for any other values in weight or ratio

My tried answer:

Liquid A in first sol= 1/7 * 1L = 1/7 L

Liquid A in second sol= 1/9 * 1L = 1/9 L

Liquid A new sol = 1/7 + 1/9 = 16/63 L

Ratio = (16/63):(110/63) = 16:110 = 8:55

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @CT-27-3555  Show please your attempts and you'll get my solution immediately.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I am flummoxed by this problem I have at here for an hour unable to identify the right process to solve this question.

Comment: Simply add the mass of $A$ in each liquid to get the mass of $A$ in the combined liquid. Do the same for $B$ and find the ratio, no? Mass is additive.

Comment: @CT-27-3555  Just show what you tried, even if you think that it's not right process.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I did exactly what "ShubramJohri" above did but it seemed wrong as the question on the worksheet was said to be 3 marks

Comment: @CT-27-3555 Could you as the details of that calculation to your question post? (Even if the result isn't correct. Maybe especially _because_ the result isn't correct.) This is exactly the kind of things we want people to include in their posts, as it makes it a lot easier for us to assess what you're struggling with so that we can write an answer that actually _helps you_.

Comment: @Arthur I understand how that would be preferable here I've attached my work above in my edited post

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I've attached my working out above for you to see

Comment: @CT-27-3555 I got the same result and posted it hour ago.

Comment: Your result is correct.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Where did you post it I was unable to see it. But anyway thank you for confirming my answer

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thank you for confirming my answer. I just asked the question Because I was unsure on my teachers marking process. I'll ask him about it in our class next week.

Comment: @CT-27-3555  See  below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|A|=\frac{1}{7}$ and $|B|=\frac{6}{7}$ in the first solution.

$|A|=\frac{1}{9}$ and $|B|=\frac{8}{9}$ in the second solution.

Thus, the needed ratio it's:$$\frac{\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}}{\frac{6}{7}+\frac{8}{9}}=8:55$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have $n$ liquids with masses $V_1,V_2,...,V_n$ and ratios of $A:B$ as $a_1:b_1,a_2:b_2,...,a_n:b_n$ respectively.

For each liquid, the mass of $A$ is $V^A_i=\frac{a_i}{a_i+b_i}V_i$ and the mass of $B$ is $V_i^B=\frac{b_i}{a_i+b_i}V_i$. Note that $V_i^A+V_i^B=V_i$ for all $i$, as expected.

Now you combine them into a homogeneous liquid of mass $V=\sum_{i=1}^nV_i$. This combined liquid has mass of $A,V^A=\sum_{i=1}^nV_i^A=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{a_i+b_i}V_i$ and mass of $B,V^B=\sum_{i=1}^nV_i^B=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{a_i+b_i}V_i$. Once again note that $V^A+V^B=V$ as expected.

Thus $$\frac{V^A}{V^B}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{a_i+b_i}V_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{a_i+b_i}V_i}=\frac{V^A}{V-V^A}$$Can you apply this scheme to your question and find the answer?